# When I change one GPIO pin output, others also change

Tags: c, mmap, gpio

I implement GPIO via mmap in C. Now I need to use GPIO to simulate I2C, but when I change the output of one pin, the level of the other pin is pulled low. I think I use AND and OR operations to change the value of a pin will not change the value of other pins, what is wrong with my operation? here is my code and pic:

```c
void i2cSDA(u8* map_base, bool isHigh)
{
    (*(volatile u32*)(map_base + GPIO_BASE_OFFSET + rPE_DAT)) = (isHigh) ?
    ((PE_DAT & 0XFFFFEFFF) | 0X00001000):
    ((PE_DAT & 0XFFFFEFFF));
}

void i2cSCL(u8* map_base, bool isHigh)
{
    (*(volatile u32*)(map_base + GPIO_BASE_OFFSET + rPE_DAT)) = (isHigh) ?
    ((PE_DAT & 0XFFFFF7FF) | 0X00000800):
    ((PE_DAT & 0XFFFFF7FF));
}
```

and in main.c:

```c
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    static int dev_fd;
    unsigned char *map_base;

    dev_fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR);

    map_base = (unsigned char *)mmap(NULL, MAP_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, dev_fd, GPIO_PAGE_OFFSET);

    i2cInit(map_base);

    i2cSCL(map_base, 1);
    i2cDely();
    i2cSDA(map_base, 1);

    i2cDely();

    i2cSDA(map_base, 0);

    i2cDely();

    i2cSDA(map_base, 1);

    i2cDely();

    close(dev_fd);

    return 0;
}
```

and PE_DAT is defined as `u32 PE_DAT = (*(volatile u32*)(map_base+GPIO_BASE_OFFSET+rPE_DAT));`

I use PE12 and PE11, the data register is 32 bits, 0:12 is data for PE0 to PE12, and 13:32 is reserved.

[image: problem like this]

When I try to pull the yellow line to high, the green line get low. [Full Code is Here](https://github.com/SwordofMorning/F1C100S_Demo), mainly used I2C.h and GPIO.h.

Comment: What is `PE_DAT`? Can you read the register directly but for writing you need to use that `map_base` thingy?

Comment: `((PE_DAT & 0XFFFFF7FF) | 0X00000800)` There is no need to clear the bit first if you want to set it anyway. Just use `(PE_DAT | 0X00000800)`

Comment: @Gerhardh `u32 PE_DAT = (*(volatile u32*)(map_base+GPIO_BASE_OFFSET+rPE_DAT));`

Comment: Where and when do you assign that value? You must update it each time you toggle the bts in the register. Can you be sure that is contains the correct value before you call `i2cSCL(map_base, 1);`. Please edit your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because your code it not sufficient to see what you are doing.

Comment: Your usage of bitmask looks strange.
I have no idea why you use the expression `(PE_DAT & 0XFFFFEFFF) | 0X00001000`
which just equals to `PE_DAT`. In general we will use `PE_DAT & 0XFFFFEFFF` to lower the
12th bit and `PE_DAT | 0x00001000` to raise it.

Comment: @tshiono The expression does not equal `PE_DAT`. It sets the bit. The expression is basically correct but more complex than needed.

Comment: My assumption is that you never set `PE_DAT` correctly and hence all bits except for the pin you are changing, are set to 0. But without MCVE that's just blind guessing.

Comment: @Gerhardh Hi, I have update the github link in problem description.

Comment: Please show all relevant code (that is a reduced example) directly in the question. This question cannot be useful for other people if external links change or go stale.

Comment: I could not find any code where you update `PE_DAT` after changing any bit.

Comment: You are doing wrong from the start. Never access hardware registers from user space in multi-user multi-tasking OS like this. This is racy and error prone, moreover it may lead to subtle and hard-to-debug bugs, including in some cases physical damages of the hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your funcktions to set/clear bits are wrong:

```c
void i2cSDA(u8* map_base, bool isHigh)
{
    (*(volatile u32*)(map_base + GPIO_BASE_OFFSET + rPE_DAT)) = (isHigh) ?
    ((PE_DAT & 0XFFFFEFFF) | 0X00001000):
    ((PE_DAT & 0XFFFFEFFF));
}
```

You never update `PE_DAT` which makes it contain old invalid values.
Also your expressions are too complicated.
This function should looke like this:

```c
void i2cSDA(u8* map_base, bool isHigh)
{
    if (isHigh != 0)
    {
        (*(volatile u32*)(map_base + GPIO_BASE_OFFSET + rPE_DAT)) |= 0X00001000;
    }
    else
    {
        (*(volatile u32*)(map_base + GPIO_BASE_OFFSET + rPE_DAT)) &= 0XFFFFEFFF;
    }
}
```